# How To Skip Down by 1 Row/Cell The Formula Output and Remove The Last Sequential Output Before 1's Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter, google-sheets-formula, countif

I've got these 3 groups of data in range `F2:G22` as below

(3 groups as minimal example, in reality many thousands of groups, and recurrent similar datasets expected in the future):

[image: i1]

I need to number each group's rows sequentially, starting over at 1 at each new group.

The expected result would be like in range `E1:E22`.

I tried the following formula n cell `C2` , then in cell `D3`:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A22="",COUNTIFS(B2:B22&A2:A22, B2:B22&A2:A22, ROW(B2:B22), "<="&ROW(B2:B22)),1))
```

## In `C2`:

[image: i1]

## In `D3`:

[image: i2]

That fixed partially the sequence issue, but there's still 2 issues I can't find remedy for.

## 1st remaining issue:

I'd prefer not having to manually do the `C2` to `D3` step each time I get new similar data (but would accomodate if there's no simple solution to this issue).

Is there a simple way to modify the formula to make it output the correct sequencing from `C2` ?

## 2nd remaining issue:

At rows 7, 14 and 23 there still remain unecessary ending numbering for these intermediary rows in `D7` , `D14` , and `D23`:

[image: i3]

I could only think of an extra manual step of filtering out the non-blank rows in Column A to fix this 2nd issue (i.e. Highlighting Column A > Data tab > Create Filter > Untick all > Tick Blanks > Copy All > Paste In new Sheet).

But would there be a way to do it in the same formula? I'm not seeing the way to add the proper filter or using another method in the formula.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT (Sorry for Forgotten Sample):**

| Formula Input A | Formula Input B | Formula Output 1 | Formula Output 2 | EXPECTED RESULT | rockinfreakshow | ztiaa | DATA | DATA BY GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 |  | 1 |  |  |  | 1 | 7 |  |
|  | 7 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | Element-1 | Group-1 |
|  | 7 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | Element-2 | Group-1 |
|  | 7 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | Element-3 | Group-1 |
|  | 7 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | Element-4 | Group-1 |
| 8 |  | 1 | 5 |  |  | 6 | 8 |  |
|  | 8 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 | Element-1 | Group-2 |
|  | 8 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 8 | Element-2 | Group-2 |
|  | 8 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 9 | Element-3 | Group-2 |
|  | 8 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 10 | Element-4 | Group-2 |
|  | 8 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 11 | Element-5 | Group-2 |
|  | 8 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 12 | Element-6 | Group-2 |
| 9 |  | 1 | 7 |  |  | 13 | 9 |  |
|  | 9 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 14 | Element-1 | Group-3 |
|  | 9 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 15 | Element-2 | Group-3 |
|  | 9 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 16 | Element-3 | Group-3 |
|  | 9 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 17 | Element-4 | Group-3 |
|  | 9 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 18 | Element-5 | Group-3 |
|  | 9 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 19 | Element-6 | Group-3 |
|  | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 20 | Element-7 | Group-3 |
|  | 9 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 21 | Element-8 | Group-3 |
|  |  |  | 9 |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: any sheet sample?

Comment: It felt I had soething missing... Sorry @player0 I went out and forgot the table, corrected above.

Comment: For later reference and ease of search as related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449393/how-to-increment-only-if-cell-is-not-empty-on-input-with-ifna-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(y,z,  
IF(LEN(z),COUNTIFS(y,y,ROW(z),"<="&ROW(z)),))
(LOOKUP(ROW(G2:G),FILTER(ROW(G2:G),BYROW(G2:G,LAMBDA(z,IF(z<>OFFSET(z,-1,0),row(z),0))))),G2:G))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: the above formula takes into account a consecutive duplicate group as a unique group of itself (as you can see in the screenshot Column_G `Group-1` repeats from row 15 after the first set in rows 3-6). But if your dataset Column_G doesn't accommodate such duplication scenarios you could go with this simple one maybe `=BYROW(G2:G,LAMBDA(aixx,IF(aixx="",,COUNTIF(G2:aixx,aixx))))`

Comment: @rockingfreakshow thank you! Works great on preliminary testing as here: https://i.imgur.com/8FfPi0F.png I'll test on extended datasets asa. Be well!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use SCAN.

```
=SCAN(,G2:G,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",,a+1)))
```

[image]

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13hW0SOqOkvW8K-lTQKFb7jxtd0q3LZ0llKnMhniQg94/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: thanks for the solution too! Very interesting, I just discovered the `SCAN` function thanks to you. Working as expected too: https://i.imgur.com/cCeAR9C.png Many thanks! Be well!