# How to increment only if cell is not empty on input with IFNA in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I found this prior answer to the issue here:

[How to increment only if cell is not empty](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/146577196/how-to-increment-only-if-cell-is-not-empty?hl=en)

But how to make it work on columns with IFNAs as blanks?

Demo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGOr6.gif

[Sample sheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQIjiLjQ-t4EDohoVvwpmaFSTDRrtnXjromp9bUNwT4/edit?usp=sharing)

Table:

| 1 | Test ONE and only. |  | 1 | ONE |  | 1 | ONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 2 |  |  | 2 |  |
| 2 | Test TWO and only. |  | 3 | TWO |  | 3 | TWO |
|  |  |  | 4 |  |  | 4 |  |
| 3 | Test THREE and only. |  | 5 | THREE |  | 5 | THREE |
|  |  |  | 6 |  |  | 6 |  |
| 4 | Test FOUR and only. |  | 7 | FOUR |  | 7 | FOUR |
|  |  |  | 8 |  |  | 8 |  |
|  |  |  | 9 |  |  | 9 |  |
|  |  |  | 10 |  |  | 10 |  |
| 5 | Test FIVE and only. |  | 11 | FIVE |  | 11 | FIVE |
|  |  |  | 12 |  |  | 12 |  |

Formulas:

`A1:B12`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    countifs(row(B1:B), "<=" & row(B1:B), B1:B, "<>") 
    / 
    not(isblank(B1:B)) 
  ) 
)
```

`D1:D12`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    countifs(row(E1:E), "<=" & row(E1:E), E1:E, "<>") 
    / 
    not(isblank(E1:E)) 
  ) 
)
```

```
=IFNA(ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B,"\b([A-Z]{2,})+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b")),"")
```

I tried solution with IFNA as below but it's not working.

`G1:H12`:

```
=IFNA(arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    countifs(row(H1:H), "<=" & row(H1:H), H1:H, "<>") 
    / 
    not(isblank(H1:H)) 
  ) 
),"")
```

```
=IFNA(ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(E1:E,"\b([A-Z]{2,})+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b")),"")
```

Your solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For later reference and ease of search as related questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345544/how-to-skip-down-by-1-row-cell-the-formula-output-and-remove-the-last-sequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(E:E),,SCAN(,E:E,LAMBDA(a,c,a+NOT(ISNA(c))))))
```

#### Update

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF(D:D="",,SCAN(,D:D,LAMBDA(a,c,a+(IFNA(c)<>""))))))
```

Comment: Works great, but needs the input to be with visible `#N/A` (G:H) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQIjiLjQ-t4EDohoVvwpmaFSTDRrtnXjromp9bUNwT4/edit#gid=1774121300 Any fix working with `#N/A` 's invisible? as in (D:E) Many Thanks! Be well!

Comment: Sorry for coming back late. I found another use case with regex that gives some troubles here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQIjiLjQ-t4EDohoVvwpmaFSTDRrtnXjromp9bUNwT4/edit#gid=42150428 I tried to update your formulas in cols D and E (input and logical checks in cols F, G, H. C is same attempt to no avail with @rochinfreakshow's formula).
Any fix for cols D and E? The blank cells are not #N/A anymore but still not empty. All I could think of using is the the regex logical Check. Thanks!

Comment: what's the desired result? And could you give edit rights?

Comment: Sure, the expected result would be as before: simple incrementing by 1 at each "non-blank" cells. For the edits right I'm not sure because @TheMaster told me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/74234209/10789707 (1st comment) people could abuse the email for spam when you do it. And to use the SO table feature instead of Sample sheets to keep a data reproducible example in case the OP deletes the Sample sheets later here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/161855#161855 Would it do making a local copy instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=index(if(H:H="",,scan(,H:H,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,a+1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Works great as needed. @ztiaa works great as well but requires `#N/A` to be visible, while this one does not: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQIjiLjQ-t4EDohoVvwpmaFSTDRrtnXjromp9bUNwT4/edit#gid=3778619
Prefered solution so far. I've notified @ztiaa and will see if the formula can be updated. Many Thanks! Be well!

Comment: @ztiaa's update works now. Yours is great too! Would tick it as well as accepted if it were possible. Thanks again @rockinfreakshow!

Comment: Sorry for coming back late. I found another use case with regex that gives some troubles here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQIjiLjQ-t4EDohoVvwpmaFSTDRrtnXjromp9bUNwT4/edit#gid=42150428 I tried to update your formula in cols C (input and logical checks in cols F, G, H. D, E is same attempt to no avail with @ztiaa's formulas).
Any fix for col C? The blank cells in Col F are not #N/A anymore but still not empty. All I could think of using is the the regex logical Check. Thanks!

Comment: try: `=index(lambda(z,if(z="",,scan(,z,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,a+1)))))(regexreplace(F:F,"^\s+$","")))`

Comment: Great help, as always, works like a charm! Thank you, really appreciated.

Comment: I think I might make it a new question for ease of searching for others' benefit. Please let me know when you're online and I'll do it and accept your answer.